# Cheerio - Find and print all attributes that match query

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio

If I have the following html code:

```
<a class="my-lovely-name" title="hello" href="fb.com">Random stuff</a>
<div class="my-lovel-name" title="ew" href="yb.com">blabla</div>
```

How can I extract all the values of `title` and `href` using cheerio? I tried the following but it would only extracts `hello` and `fb.com` and skips the remaining elements:

```
console.log($('.my-lovely-name').attr('title')) => should print the titles of all elements with this class
console.log($('.my-lovely-name').attr('href')) => => should print the href-s of all elements with this class
```

Comment: `attr()` only returns the value for the first element in the result stack.  https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to map them into an array.

```
console.log(
  $('.my-lovely-name').map(
    (index, element) => element.title
  ).get()
)
```

Ref. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio#map-functionindex-element-

Answer (score 0):

```
$('..my-lovely-name').map((index, element) => {
    const attributes = element.attribs;
    Object.keys(attributes).map(key => {
        console.log(key, ': ', attributes[key]);
    })
});
```

By this you will get list of all attributes in your html element, then you can filter the one that you are interested in.